# Creating Sprite Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Please tell me, what is the easiest way to programmaticaly create tk2dSprite in toolkit2d(unity)?
So I have .png image in assets/image from which sprite must be created. 
I want to create sprite, and then show it on the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not at my computer but try something like (C#):

```
string spriteName = "spriteInSpriteCollection";
GameObject spriteObject = new GameObject();
tk2dSprite spriteComponent = spriteObject.AddComponent<tk2dSprite>();
spriteComponent.SetSprite(spriteName);
```

I would test this and see if the component could be created and initialized with the sprite before adding it to the object but I can't right now, hopefully this points you in the right direction though.

Edited to include improvement by SlxS.

Comment: It's slightly more efficient to do tk2dSprite spriteComponent = spriteObject.AddComponent<tk2dSprite>(); spriteComponent.SetSprite(spriteName);

That way you won't have to perform a slow GetComponent call.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I knew there was something off about my answer, I had forgotten AddComponent<> returns the component itself.